# Using Dictionary As Item Within Another Dictionary to Count Unique Values

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, excel-formula

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

I have an ID in Column DA.  I have a product in Column CB.  I want to count the number of unique products for each ID (ID can have multiple lines).  I then want to write the number of unique products to a new column (DB).

My logic was to write two dictionaries.  The "main" dictionary would be keyed to the ID and the second dictionary would be keyed to my products.  In the main dictionary, if the key exists I would retrieve the item into a dict object, if it doesn't exist then I'd re-write the main dictionary.

After this, I was thinking of using .count function to tell me how many unique values existed for each ID.

I have been trying to adapt some code to fit my needs.  Here is what I have currently:

```
Sub Find_Unique_Product_Number()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Worksheets("Orders").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    adata = Worksheets("Orders").Range("A1:DB" & LastRow)

    Set dicTwoProds = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")     'Late binding    creation of dictionary
        For LastRow = LBound(adata, 1) To UBound(adata, 1)
            sKey1 = adata(LastRow, 80)
            If Not dicTwoProds.Exists(sKey) Then
                Set dicItem = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

                dicTwoProds.Add sKey1, aItem

                sKey1 = Worksheets("Orders").Range("CB2:CB" & LastRow)           'Product
                dicTwoProdsItem.Add sKey1, ""                              

            Else
                Set dicItem = dicTwoProd.Item(sKey)
                sKey2 = Worksheets("Orders").Range("CB2:CB" & LastRow)                                              'Product
                If Not dicItem.Exists(sKey2) Then
                    dicItem.Add sKey2, ""                            
                    dicTwoProds.Item(sKey) = aItem
                End If
            End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Currently this code throws an "object required" error on this line: `dicTwoProdsItem.Add sKey1, ""`

I am guessing part of my issue is how I am using .range on the sKey lines?  I am unsure of how that syntax should be.

I am not sure how writing the .count results to the sheet would work at all yet.

I do have an array formula that does what I need which is this:
       `'=SUM(IF(DA5=DA2:DA100,1/ (COUNTIFS(DA2:DA100,DA5,CB2:CB100,CB2:CB100)),0))`

The formula is extremely slow which is part of the reason I wanted to use dictionaries.  If the dictionary solution does not work, I would be interested in assistance with the syntax for using VBA to place the array formula into Column DB on my worksheet.

All data is on the same worksheet in the described scenario.

Cheers!

Comment: What is `aItem`? I can't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: More pertinently, what is `dicTwoProdsItem`?

Comment: @SJR You're right...It's not defined.  From what I understand `aItem` would be my "item" to tie to the sKey, I think I want the item to be the second dictionary? So I'm not sure how that would look.  I apologize, the goal in general is a bit of reach for me capability wise.

Comment: @SJR I think I messed up there, I just need `dicItem.Add sKey1, ""`

Comment: Or maybe `dicTwoProds.Add sKey1, ""`? Sorry, don't have time to look closely now - somebody else will.

Comment: @SJR no worries, thanks for getting the conversation started!

Comment: Try changing ` adata = Worksheets("Orders").Range("A1:DB" & LastRow)` for ` adata = Worksheets("Orders")` and `sKey1 = adata(LastRow, 80)` for `sKey1 = adata.Range("CB & LastRow)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a single `Dictionary` to count the number of unique products for each ID.

The trick is to concatenate the id with the product to create a unique key:

```
Dim dict As Object, lastRow As Long, r As Long, ids(), products(), dupIds()
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

lastRow =  Worksheets("Orders").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ids =      Worksheets("Orders").Range("DA2:DA" & lastRow).Value
products = Worksheets("Orders").Range("CB2:CB" & lastRow).Value

' map the id to each unique id/product '

For r = LBound(ids) To UBound(ids)
    dict(ids(r, 1) & products(r, 1)) = CStr(ids(r, 1))
Next

' map the count of products to each unique id '

dupIds = dict.Items
dict.RemoveAll

For r = LBound(dupIds) To UBound(dupIds)
    dict(dupIds(r)) = dict(dupIds(r)) + 1
Next

' build the column holding the count of products '

For r = LBound(ids) To UBound(ids)
    products(r, 1) = dict(CStr(ids(r, 1)))
Next

Worksheets("Orders").Range("DB2:DB" & lastRow).Value = products
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly something like this should work.
(Simplified for a 2-column dataset)

```
Sub Find_Unique_Product_Number()

    Dim dict As Object, i As Long, id, prod, adata, k, k2
    Dim rngDest As Range

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Worksheets("Orders")
        adata = Worksheets("Orders").Range("A1:B" & _
                         .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With

    For i = LBound(adata, 1) To UBound(adata, 1)
        id = adata(i, 1)
        prod = adata(i, 2)
        If Len(id) > 0 And Len(prod) > 0 Then
            'New id? Add as key with empty dictionary
            If Not dict.exists(id) Then dict.Add id, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            'increment the count for this combination
            dict(id)(prod) = dict(id)(prod) + 1
        End If
    Next

    'EDIT: output the counts
    Set rngDest = Worksheets("Summary").Range("A2")
    For Each k In dict.keys
        For Each k2 In dict(k).keys
            rngDest.Resize(1, 3).Value = Array(k, k2, dict(k)(k2))
            Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1, 0)
        Next k2
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I adjusted the ranges to test on my data and I believe (from checking the immediate window) that this does what I need!  I tried to adjust the `Debug.Print` so it would write to my worksheet in order to verify it is really giving the expected results, but am not having much luck.  I did some quick searching on the site as well as google but didn't see an example of converting Debug.Print to something like a loop with `.Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Value = dict(k).Keys` that would output to my sheet. I know my `.range...` is not correct, but unsure of the correct method?

Comment: See my edit for one approach - you should be able to revise that to do what you need.

Comment: Thank you for providing the edit Tim.  When I tried this, it was providing me some incorrect counts (ex. I would have a single row for an ID but output to sheet would count 2 different products).  Due to time constrictions, I am using the answer below, as this seems to work for me.  The answer you provided is very useful to me regardless.